# Custom authentication scheme invoked after authorization middleware

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

We are rebuilding a Web API with .Net 6.

When adding in the authentication we need two authentication schemes, JWT and a custom token scheme.

The custom authentication scheme is used to pull out a token (a randomly generated alphanumeric string) from the header, check it against a stored value in the database and validate the expiry date. This is required to support the old authentication method in the previous API as downloaded apps are still connecting this way.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer()
    .AddScheme<CustomAuthenticationOptions, CustomAuthentication>(
        "CustomAuthentication",
        "Custom Authentication",
        options => {}
    );
```

When registering the middleware we want to add some custom roles from our database, so have a custom middleware after authentication but before the roles have been authorized.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This works great for the JWT Bearer authentication but doesn't for the custom authentication scheme.

The `AuthMiddleware` gets invoked before our `CustomAuthentication` does, meaning we are not authenticated before we add custom roles.

If we move the `app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();` after `app.UseAuthorization();` then the `CustomAuthentication` is called before `AuthMiddleware` but the roles have already been authorized and the API returns unauthorized as expected.

### Question

Why does `AddJwtBearer()` call authentication and middleware at the correct time, but my custom scheme does not? Or is there a better way to do custom authentication?

### Simplified files for reference

*CustomAuthentication.cs*

```
public class CustomAuthentication : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthentication(
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock
    ) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // This is called too late
    }
}
```

*AuthMiddleware.cs*

```
public class AuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if ((httpContext.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated).GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            // This is not authenticated for custom authentication
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you have both a custom auth handler and middleware. If you want a DB lookup for a JWT Bearer token, you can implement `IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>` then add claims in `options.Events.OnTokenValidated` https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-jwt-saving-bearer-token-as-claim/

Comment: It would help if you described the purpose of your custom authentication. Does your custom auth issue a challenge (eg 3xx & location header, or 4xx & authentication header)? And how your endpoints are authorised. Do you have endpoints that should allow either authentication scheme? Or are the endpoints split into two groups that should only be allowed for a single scheme?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman,  I have edited the question to describe the purpose of the custom authentication. The reason there is both an auth handler and middleware is that the JWT and custom authentication use the middleware to add additional roles to the request. The custom auth doesn't issue a challenge it runs the `HandleAuthenticateAsync()` to check the properties of the request and validates them. Some of the endpoints need access to both authentication schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your custom roles function from `AuthMiddleware` into a new service. Removing your `AuthMiddleware` entirely.

Then hook the jwt bearer `OnTokenValidated` event to add role claims to the authenticated principal;

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
    if (options.Events == null)
        options.Events = new();
    var validate = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context => {
        var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<...>();
        await service.AddDbRoles(context.Principal);
    };
})
```

With a similar implementation within your `CustomAuthentication` handler.

Comment: I assume authentication is not designed to have middleware with `app.UseMiddleware();` and that is why this doesn't work. I think using events from within the authentication options is where this logic is designed to sit so will follow this advice.